# How to get list string from Hashtable?

Tags: c#, list, hashtable

I don't how to get list values

```
Hashtable hshTable = new Hashtable();
List<string> l= new List<string>();
l.Add("string1");
l.Add("string2");
hshTable.Add("1",l);
```

try

```
string temp= hshTable["1"][0];
```

error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Is there any reason that you prefer the `Hashtable` collection over a [`Dictionary<string, List<string>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation and error message, `Hashtable.Item[Object]` returns `object`.

```cs
public virtual object? this[object key] { get; set; }
```

You should cast the value as `List<string>` type before getting the value by index.

```cs
string temp= ((List<string>)hshTable["1"])[0];
```

Comment: While the [documentation mentions it is not recommended to use Hashtable for new development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-7.0#remarks).